# How to get the class of a variable

Tags: java

In Java, given the line

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

`myList.getClass()` returns `ArrayList`.

Is there a way to find the type `myList` was declared with, in this case `List`?

Comment: if the possibilites are few, then you can use instanceof operator in if else statements

Comment: try Use "instanceof" like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: I know of the instanceof, but I need my function to be agnostic of the possible types, since there are many.

Comment: @ofir that's JavaScript, not Java

Comment: `instanceof` will be true both for `ArrayList` and `List`.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out the superclass of a given class using `getSuperClass()`:

> Returns the Class representing the superclass of the entity (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class. If this Class represents either the Object class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned.

This will give you the top most parent class:

```
    List myList = new ArrayList();
    Class superClass = myList.getClass().getSuperclass();
    System.out.println(superClass.getSimpleName());
```

This might not be what you were asking for directly as you wanted to get the specific class in the super chain (`List` in this case) but this should be of some help.

**Edit**: Here is a simple way I found on this [page](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/java/reflection/get-parent-class.html) that will get all the parents of a given class:

```
private static void printParents(Class<?> clazz) {

    while (clazz != null) {
        System.out.print(clazz.getName());

        if (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
            System.out.print(" > ");
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note that this will **not** give you all the interfaces parent classes are implementing (as is the case with `List`). For that you will need to use some form of reflection.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not specifically looking for a direct superclass.

Comment: Yea that might be a bit more tricky, read my edit.